# How to prevent from modifying a copy of dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, class, dictionary, foundation

I've got a following problem.

I have a function called **A** which takes a following dictionary as an argument `[String : MyClass]`, where **MyClass** is a custom class that I've created (it's a subclass of `NSObject`).
MyClass has a property called firstProperty.

**Function A** looks like so:

```
func A (someDictionary : [String : MyClass]) {
    var someDictionaryCopy = someDictionary

    someDictionaryCopy["Key"].updateValue()
}
```

Ok, so the *first line* in the body of the function A is copying the someDictionary that is passed to the function A. But I DON'T want to mutate or modify the original someDictionary.

The *second line*: I take some existing value in the dictionary and run a method on MyClass instance which modifies one of its properties.

The thing is that if I run the code above, the original dictionary that's passed to the function is modified as well? Why is it so? How can I pass a dictionary to the function so that it's not mutated?

For your convenience, here's a sample of MyClass implementation:

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
    var someProperty : Double = 0.0

    func updateValue() {
        someProperty += 10.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift dictionaries are value type - the original is *not* modified when you update a copy. This is the opposite of NSDictionary which is *reference* type. However, in your Swift dictionary, you have a *class*: those are reference type and will be updated from the copy.

Comment: Ok, so how do I copy a dictionary, so that the values within it are not modified?

Comment: You shouldn't work with classes if you don't want reference behavior, use structs instead. But if using classes, then embrace the reference system. This is my suggestion. :)

Comment: Change MyClass to a struct instead of a class and it will automatically work. If thats all there is to MyClass that you have shown then there is no reason for it to be a class. If there's much more to it then you have shown and it *needs* to be a class, then you will have to enable deep copying on the dictionary by making your class copyable https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy

Comment: Ok, thank you guys all. I knew that I needed to do something about NSCopying. Now everything is clear. I won't change my class to a struct, but rather make it conform to NSCopying protocol :)
Also, here's another useful link on how to actually make a class conform to NSCopying protocol: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `MyClass` is a reference type. When you copy the dictionary, it does, truly, make a new copy of the dictionary, but the new copy has references to the same instances of `MyClass` that the original dictionary has. Changes made to a copy of a reference to an instance of `MyClass` anywhere, whether it is inside a dictionary or any other value type, will be reflected in any other reference to that same instance of `MyClass`.

Basically, the dictionary is a value type, which means it has value semantics. But the values in the dictionary are reference types, so they have reference semantics. The only way around this is to create a dictionary with *new instances of `MyClass` for every key in the dictionary.* Or, as @EricD suggested, use structs instead of classes to get the value semantics that you want.